# When I run a command with yarn, how do I get the applicationId?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I'm submitting a job with the yarn `jar` command to run the distributed shell. How do I get the applicationId programmatically?

Comment: To get the application Id you need to go to ResourceManager webUI, which can be accessed by the IP addr of your node where resource manager is available and port number to use is 8088. There you can see the Application id, Container id and your job status.

Comment: @Abhinav, thanks for answering! But I don't want to use the webUI, I want this information from the command line. Presumably when yarn submits something, the information should be available. How do I get it? Otherwise, I need to recognize the job from the webUI.  Also, is there a REST interface to the webUI? I don't have a user available to look at the WebUI; I need to have this all scripted.

Comment: Not an issue. You can look the job status from CLI also. You can list all the running jobs using command **yarn application -list**  and **yarn application status <app id>**. It won't be a detailed output like you can see in web UI but will help you get the status and running jobs.

Comment: But doesn't that assume that the last job running is the one I just ran? What if there are multiple processes running Yarn jobs. I have a potential race condition.

Comment: You may be confusing with the jobs and tasks, if you enter the <app id>, it doesn't matter how many processes are undertaken by a single job, you'll get the information about all the processes. And it depends on you, whether you want to see a single application's status or the list of all the applications you have committed through yarn. Just try it out once. And let me know if that solves your query

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. Here's what's going on. We have a master program that is periodically starting up new yarn jobs with the `yarn jar` command. I'd like to be able to monitor when those jobs are finished and systematically capture their output. I can rely on the fact that the there is a jar file that matches what was just submitted, but I am worried about the potential race condition if two processes both submit a job with the same jar command, which can happen.

Comment: I might not be able to help you with that. I can only tell you that if one jar is used by different jobs then race condition might occur and there is a path available for the same. You can refer to apache patches, maybe you'll get some help there.

Comment: You've helped a lot!

Comment: PS: If you can make your comments an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @vy32. It'd be a pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **application Id** you need to go to ResourceManager Web UI, which can be accessed by the IP addr of your node where resource manager is available and port number to use is *8088*. There you can see the Application id, Container id and your job status.

You can look the job status from CLI also. You can list all the running jobs using command **yarn application -list** and **yarn application status** . It won't be a detailed output like you can see in web UI but will help you get the status and running jobs